# How do you authenticate a user against application permissions in an external web application?

Tags: facebook, oauth, authorization

I have an application that allows you to share certain data in Facebook. You can create data in my application, and then share a 'journal' of some of the information by use of a Facebook custom object I have created within my Facebook app.

When a friend clicks on the link in my user's timeline, I redirect them to the site where the Journal is displayed. The site creates all of the pertinent og meta tags and whatnot. Then it gets the data from my database based on the ID passed back from Facebook, and shows the Journal entry.  Only those who are within the authorization group the user defined for my application should be able to do this.

The problem I have is that the Facebook authentication is handled client side via JavaScript and the data collection is handled server side. I realize I can call the auth from the server, or ship the token to the server via AJAX, but both of those seem sorta hacky. I am looking for a pattern for this kind of thing, figuring that others have done it before.